# Convert a java date (time) pattern string to a SQL date pattern string

Tags: java, sql, date, design-patterns

is there a simple way to convert a date pattern string given in java
to an equivalent date pattern useable by SQL, except copious amounts of string.replace() - calls?

eg. i want to do the following in java:

```
String sqlDatePattern = myTranslator.translateToSQLPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
/*expected result: dd.MM.yyyy HH24:MI:ss*/
```

Best regards!

Comment: Take a step back: why are you trying to format the date as text in the first place? With parameterized queries, you simply shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: I dont talk about dates as parameters in the first place; my goal is that i have an internationalization mechanism somewhere in my application logic, that generates date pattern strings per locale. Now i want to use this pattern string on my database within a select: "SELECT to_char("myDate", '<Pattern Converted From java>') FROM "MyTable";  Now i want to do a COPY TO CSV on this SELECT-Statement in order to export the result to a csv-file. In order to keep it nicely readable, I want to do the mentionte conversion.

Comment: Is CSV a must? Otherwise I could recommend XML which easier to parse and supports date data types.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with this sqlDatePattern string? If you want to use it in a SQL statement, consider the following approach:

- create a java.sql.Date/Time/Timestamp from you original date pattern
- use a PreparedStatement and pass the create object as parameter

With PreparedStatements you don't have to worry about the exact format and it protects you from SQL injections.

Comment: see above; i am neither talking about dates as parameters nor about java dates/timestamps at all.